# How to apply substitution for this integral $\int \frac{dx}{x^2 + 1 + x\sqrt{x^2+2}}$

Tags: integration, substitution

I want to integrate $$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 + 1 + x\sqrt{x^2+2}}$$ and I get that I need to do a variable substitution. But how do I know what to substitute and for what? I can guess that I should substitute $\sqrt{x^2+2}$ but for what? Usually I would go for $t$ but in this case it looks like $t-x$ or something like that are more correct.

Substituting to $t-x$ gives $\int \frac{t^2+2}{t^4+6t^2+4}$ which I believe is wrong because the answer does not consist of any logaritms.

=Edit=
And in any case, what's wrong with the solution (t-x) I tried. It gives me a perfectly solvable integral, but it's still wrong, why?

=Edit 2=
Still haven't managed to solve this.

$\int \frac{1}{x^2+x+x\sqrt{x^2+2}} = \left[\sqrt{x^2+2} = t - x, x = \frac{t^2-2}{2t}, \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{t^2+2}{2t^2}, \sqrt{x^2+2} = \frac{t^2-2}{2t} \right] = \int \frac{1}{\left(\frac{t^2-2}{2t} \right)^2+1+\left(\frac{t^2-2}{2t} \right)^2}\times \frac{t^2+2}{2t^2} dt = \int \frac{t^2+2}{t^4-2t^2+4} dt$

This is going in the wrong direction since I know that the answer should be $\frac{1}{2}\left(x - \sqrt{x^2+2} - \frac{1}{6}\left(\sqrt{x^2+2}-x\right)^3\right)$ or $-\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}} - \frac{2}{3(x + \sqrt{x^2+2}^3}$

Comment: [The power that teachers don't give students anymore.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution)

Comment: Excellent link but I'm having trouble applying it in this case. I don't have $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$ but $x^2 + 1 + x\sqrt{x^2+2}$

Comment: What you have is exactly what the substitutions are for: Rational functions of $x$ and a $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$. In this case $R(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+1+xy}$, $a=1,b=0$, and $c=2$.

Comment: yes but I don't understand how to apply it. I've $ax^2+bx+c$ where $a = 1, b = \sqrt{x^2+2}, c = 1$ and that's not under a rot

Comment: No, review my comment above. Those values of $b$ and $c$ are not what you have.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it =(. Can you elaborate? (maybe as an answer so I can mark this as solved afterwards)

Comment: And in any case, what's wrong with the solution (t-x) I tried. It gives me a perfectly solvable integral, but it's still wrong, why?

Comment: This is knowing how to use a formula. The first expression in the Wikipedia page: $\int R(x,\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c})$. Your integral is of this form for $R(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+1+xy}$, $a=1$, $b=0$, and $c=2$. Since $a>0$ we can go to section 1 of the wikipedia page. It suggests the substitution $\sqrt{x^2+2}=x+t$. It also tells you $x=\frac{t^-2}{2t}$, using the formula for $x$ and the values of $a,b,c$.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the substitution $\sqrt{x^2+2}=t-x$, that in one of the options you see in the Wikipedia page, section $1$. Two things may be happening, either you did some mistake in the application of the substitution and the computation of the integral, or you got an answer that you are not noticing is equivalent to the given answer because they look different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1+x\sqrt{x^2+2}}=\int\frac{2dx}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+2})^2}$$

Use the substitution
$$y=x+\sqrt{x^2+2}$$

So $$(y-x)^2=x^2-2\Rightarrow x=\frac{y^2-2}{2y}$$

and 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{y^2-2}{2y}\right)^2+2}}=\frac{2y^2}{y^2+2}$$
Thus we have $$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{y^2+2}{2y^2}$$

This leads to the integral being
$$\int\frac{2dx}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+2})^2}=\int\frac{2(y^2+2)dy}{2y^2(y^2)}=\int\frac{dy}{y^2}+2\int\frac{dy}{y^4}\\=-\frac{1}{y}-\frac{2}{3y^3}$$

Subtituting $x$ back in, we end up with
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1+x\sqrt{x^2+2}}=\int\frac{2dx}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+2})^2}=-\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}-\frac{2}{3(x+\sqrt{x^2+2})^3}$$